# eclipse(java) wont load the workspace

Tags: java, eclipse

the first time i opened eclipse it came up with an error message and it told me to check the log. so i did. heres the log. i have tried to delete .metadata and that didnt work.

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-10-11 17:41:52.506
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/stylesheets/StyleSheet
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.internal.theme.ThemeEngineManager.getCSSSWTEngine(ThemeEngineManager.java:41)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.internal.theme.ThemeEngineManager.getEngineForDisplay(ThemeEngineManager.java:30)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createThemeEngine(PartRenderingEngine.java:1428)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.initializeStyling(PartRenderingEngine.java:1281)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1036)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:382)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:236)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.w3c.dom.stylesheets.StyleSheet cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core_0.10.100.v20140424-2042
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:423)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:336)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:328)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
... 25 more
```

Comment: This looks like it was caused by a classnotfound exception. Have you deleted or changed the path of any projects recently?

Comment: no its the first time i loaded eclipse

Comment: You are using Java 9 with an old version of Eclipse. Either use Java 8 or install Eclipse Oxygen.1a (4.7.1a) which should be released sometime today.

Comment: @greg-449 ...which has already been released: see https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/ ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The best solution as someone suggested is to install Eclipse 4.7.1a that has native support for Java 9, anyway if you have an older release of eclipse you can add :

```
--add-modules=java.se.ee
```

in the eclipse.ini file after `-vmargs`, and it will solve the problem.

Take a look at [this post](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Configure_Eclipse_for_Java_9) for more information.